# EnrichHeader based on condition

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am writing a generic adapter that gets messages from EMS and pushes into Kafka Topic. I have to enrich the header if a particular flag is set to true from the config file. Th eexpression of the header will also exist in the config file

```
return IntegrationFlows.from(org.springframework.integration.jms.dsl.Jms
        .messageDrivenChannelAdapter(org.springframework.integration.jms.dsl.Jms
                .container(this.queueConnFactory, this.queue)
                .transactionManager(transactionManager()).get()))
        .enrichHeaders(
                h -> h.headerExpression(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, "headers['flightNbr']")) 
        .handle(Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(kafkaTemplate).topic(kafkaTopic))
        .get();
```

I know how to add the headers from the received message but how can we conditionally add headers?
Also, if the flag is false headers will not be applied.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `headerFunction(String name, Function<Message<P>, ?> function)` instead of that `headerExpression()`. So, something like this should work for you:

```
              .enrichHeaders(h ->
                        h.headerFunction(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, m -> {
                            if (SOME_STATE) {
                                return m.getHeaders().get("flightNbr");
                            }
                            else {
                                return null;
                            }
                        }))
```